# Dealing with constraints for proportional squares

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, xib

I am having some problems dealing with constraints with squares. I need the squares (UIImageView) to be proportional for each iPhone size. I also need the words to stay proportional. I have tried a couple of different things but the squares seem to grow or shrink every time and go all over the place. Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: "the squares seem to grow or shrink every time and go all over the place" Then you're doing something wrong. Stop doing that. :) Seriously, the layout you've drawn is easiest to achieve using code-based layout of those views, not autolayout. You can do it in autolayout, but you'll have a much easier time if you just calculate the correct frames for all those views and assign them directly, in code.

Comment: You do realize that, since different iPhones have different aspect ratios, something has to give. You can't scale a rectangle with one aspect ratio to a rectangle with another aspect ratio and keep squares square and circles circular. If you want to keep the circles circular and keep 8 per diagonal line, then the diagonal lines of circles will have to move closer or further for different aspect ratios.

Comment: The problem with putting it in code is that it is the LaunchScreen.xib. I thought you couldn't have code for the LaunchScreen. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep 8 circles in each diagonal line, and want them anchored to the corners of the screen:

- Select all of the circles and select Editor > Pin > Widths Equally. And then do Heights Equally.
- Select one of the circles and Control-drag from it to itself, and create an Aspect Ratio constraint. Make sure its multiplier is 1:1.
- For all of the circles in a diagonal, create Horizontal Spacing constraints with 0 constant from one to the next. Same for the other diagonal. Then, the same for Vertical Spacing.
- For the top-left circle of the top diagonal, pin it to the container's top and leading edge.
- For the bottom-right circle of the top diagonal, pin its trailing edge to the container's trailing edge.
- For the bottom-right circle of the bottom diagonal, pin it to the container's bottom and trailing edge.
- For the top-left circle of the bottom diagonal, pin its leading edge to the container's leading edge.

That should get the circles to line up and size themselves proportional to the device's width.

- For the "Color" label, pin its top and bottom to the blue circle to its right. Pin its trailing edge to the blue circle's leading edge with some spacing.
- For the "Catch" label, pin its top and bottom to the green circle to its left. Pin its leading edge to the green circle's trailing edge with some spacing.
- You probably want to also create constraints for the label edges on the far side of the circle to the corresponding edge of the container, with spacing and greater-than-or-equal-to relation, to make sure they don't extend off the edge.